# Contact Form 7 not submitting using Ajax

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form that's inserted into a template using shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="370" title="Contact form 1"]') ?>
```

I'm trying to setup an event so that when the form is submitted I can redirect the user to another page. I'm using the following;

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

The problem is, when you submit the form, the whole page is reloaded so the event is never triggered because the form isn't submitted via an ajax call.

This is the first time I'm trying to integrate a form into Wordpress, so I think I may have missed something. There are no errors in the developer console in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your theme (check functions.php) or your wp-config.php file, you need to look for and remove the following:

functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

config.php

```
define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false );
```

These lines would prevent the default behavior of CF7.

Comment: I checked functions.php and config.php, neither of those lines of code exist.

Comment: Perhaps you have another plugin installed that is doing this?  Contact form 7 defaults to Ajax submission unless it's purposefully turned off.

Comment: The only plugins installed, are contact form 7, ACF Pro, Reading Time WP, WP user Avatar, Yoast Duplicate Post and Yoast SEO. All pretty standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My theme was missing;

Adding that solved the issue.